# Error message: "Binary detected: Linked publishing of components has been disabled."

Tags: publishing, publishingfailed

I got this error today for the first time and have no idea what it means.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You would have to provide more information, such as a Stack Trace of the error.

Comment: Or some indication of where it shows

Comment: Hi Bryan welcome to Stack Exchange. It would be great if you can provide stack trace. If you don't know where to look at them, you can check in event viewer, or if you have logging on Content Manager or In Content Delivery, then from there. It would be also good if you can specify at which stage of publishing is this happening.

Comment: And check/confirm if you have custom extensions installed... could be something specifically coded to catch binaries {of a certain type/in a specific location or whatever}

Comment: Hi @Bryan, are you facing issue while preview/publish of component/page?

Answer (score 0):

This is message is created through a GUI extension. Please reach out to your administrator group for more information.